# SSRS Visibility

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Having trouble with my SSRS Visibility expression:

```
=IIF((SUM(Fields!Rooms_Off_2) = 0 AND (IsNothing(Fields!actual_end.Value)))               
OR (SUM(Fields!Rooms_Off_2) = 0 AND (Fields!actual_end.Value >= DATEADD("d",-7,TODAY()))), false, true)
```

Keeps giving me the error message: "The Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ uses an aggregate function with an expression that returned a data type not valid for the aggregate function. (rsProcessingError)"

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to be missing `.Value` from both `Fields!Rooms_Off_2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `Rooms_Off_2` field is set to `Text` data type which cannot be used in an aggregation function like `SUM`. You can convert that field to a Double data type in order to get the aggregation working.

Try:

```
Switch(
SUM(CDbl(Fields!Rooms_Off_2)) = 0 AND IsNothing(Fields!actual_end.Value),False,
SUM(CDbl(Fields!Rooms_Off_2)) = 0 AND Fields!actual_end.Value >= DATEADD("d",-7,TODAY()),False,
True,True  
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That is why I am confused, the Rooms_Off_2 field is actually a field created by a CASE statement:         `CASE WHEN snapshot_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-11,CONVERT(CHAR(8), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,112))
           AND DATEADD(dd,-5,CONVERT(CHAR(8), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,112))
   THEN rooms_off_market ELSE 0 END AS [Rooms Off 2],`

Comment: I also have the SUM(Rooms_Off_2) as a column within my report and everything comes out fine, until I add the visibility expression.

Comment: @Femmer, where are you using that expression in a tablix, a textbox or a property?

Comment: It is a column within a tablix.

Comment: @Femmer, I think your issue is that you are trying to conditionally set the visibility expression using multiple rows. What `actual_end` value do you think will be used to evaluate the conditional?.

Comment: I want to be visible if it is blank or if it has a date that is greater than last week. I can do that, but when I use the SUM it still sums the data that is not showing.

Comment: @Femmer, share sample data and explain the expected result in order to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: So I am much better at writing queries, so I just reworked the dataset. The query doesn't look pretty, but it does the job. Thanks for the help!